# Getting access permission for user_birthday on facebook without submitting app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an app which requires me to have the user's date of birth so I can calculate their age. I'm using Facebook to authenticate the user, but I can't get access to the user_birthday permission on the GraphAPI unless I actually submit the app.

How can I get around this? The app is only in development at the moment, and I won't actually be able to finish it *unless I can get access to the user_birthday* property?

I believe I can get age ranges, but that's no use to me at all. I'm developing the app alone, and using only facebook accounts that I own, so no security risk at all.

Is there another way I can approach getting this permission? Or perhaps a workaround for development purposes? Am I missing something?

(app is being written in Flutter, and using a Firebase backend).

Comment: You can ask all users that have a role in your app for these permissions, when your app is in dev mode, it does not have to be reviewed for that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. My 3 facebook accounts are all admins on the app, but the user_birthday property is still hidden? The app is in development mode too (not live), so everything should be correct, but it isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of messing about, it seems I've found the answer. This is pretty ambiguous in the FB documentation, but it seems you have to request access to `user_birthday` in the initial login permissions, followed by just `birthday` in your GraphAPI request.

Comment: Of course you have to _ask_ for the permissions, they are not automatically granted, just because the user you are testing with is an app admin.

Comment: That wasn't the point of what I was saying - I was highlighting the point that the string you ask for isn't the same. I was using ```user_birthday``` in both requests, but it's ```user_birthday``` in one and ```birthday``` in the other. There was no misunderstanding when it came to actually asking for permissions...

Comment: Ah, okay. Well the one is the permission, and the other is the field name. There is no 1:1 relation between those, there are permissions that allow access to multiple fields.